# Sort a list of filenames such that files in subdirectories are listed before files in the parent directory

Tags: filenames, sort

I have a text file containing a list of files, such as:

```
file
A1/file
A1/B1/file
A2/file
```

How can I sort it such that files in subdirectories are listed before other files in the parent directory?

```
A1/B1/file
A1/file
A2/file
file
```

Comment: If the file was created using `find`, then adjusting the arguments that were used with that command would be the easiest approach as it wouldn't require any post-processing steps. Simply adding `-depth` would likely be enough. This is not an answer as there is no information in the question about the origin of the data.

Comment: If it helps, the origin of the data is output of diff on a directory (git diff to be specific), with the initial characters stripped `M     ./`

Comment: `git diff` also produces an actual diff of the file contents, so I presume that it's not a straight `git diff`.

Comment: git --no-pager diff --name-status origin/master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zsh` has the `od` glob qualifier to `o`rder glob expansions `d`epth-first,

```
$ print -rC1 -- **/file(Nod)
A2/file
A1/B1/file
A1/file
file
```

That can be applied to an arbitrary list of files, if that list of files is loaded into a glob expansion using the `e` qualifier.

```
$ print -rC1 -- /(Ne['reply=( ${(f)"$(<your-file)"} )']od)
A2/file
A1/B1/file
A1/file
file
```

Also sorted by name with `on`:

```
$ print -rC1 -- /(Ne['reply=( ${(f)"$(<your-file)"} )']odon)
A1/B1/file
A1/file
A2/file
file
```

Answer (score 3):

Here a simple way:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"; OFS="\t"}{print NF, $0}' file | sort -rn | cut -f2-
```

```
A1/B1/file
A2/file
A1/file
file
```

Should works for simple cases, like your question.

If you want to sort also by dirs:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"; OFS="\t"}{print NF, $0}' file | sort -k1,1rn -k2 | cut -f2-
```

```
A1/B1/file
A1/file
A2/file
file
```

Comment: `awk -F/ '{printf "%d\t%s\n", NF, $0}' file | sort -k1,2rn -k2,99 | cut -f2` will sort items at the same level correctly

Comment: Neither of these list subdirectories before files. Maybe misleading to have asked for "depth first" when what I actually want is in the body of the question, subdirectories before files in the same directory. Neither of the solutions so far do that either. If I add A2/B1/C1/file to the directory, I want to see:
A1/B1/file
A1/file
A2/B1/C1/file
A2/file
file

Comment: I am going to repost this question properly

Comment: @KenTaylor please don't. Instead, edit this one and clarify what you need.

Comment: @KenTaylor, "_what I actually want is […] subdirectories before files in the same directory_" - this isn't what your question asks

Comment: Sorry. Does now. Seems confusing to change the question but that is what I have been asked to do.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the insights of @Kusalananda, if indeed these filenames are the complete contents of an extant directory tree, `find` can do what you want:

Given:

```
$ find .
./f2
./A1
./A1/B1
./A1/B1/f2
./A1/B1/f1
./A1/f2
./A1/f1
./A2
./A2/B1
./A2/B1/C1
./A2/B1/C1/f2
./A2/B1/C1/f1
./A2/f2
./A2/f1
./f1
```

GNU `find` can:

```
$ find . -depth -type d -exec find {} -maxdepth 1 -not -type d \;
./A1/B1/f2
./A1/B1/f1
./A1/f2
./A1/f1
./A2/B1/C1/f2
./A2/B1/C1/f1
./A2/f2
./A2/f1
./f2
./f1
```

If you care about the sorting of files within a directory, GNU find lets you down, having no controls over the ordering.  You might have to do something like:

```
$ find . -depth -type d -exec sh -c 'find {} -maxdepth 1 -not -type d | sort' \;
./A1/B1/f1
./A1/B1/f2
./A1/f1
./A1/f2
./A2/B1/C1/f1
./A2/B1/C1/f2
./A2/f1
./A2/f2
./f1
./f2
```

The `find` utility on FreeBSD and NetBSD will recognize the `-s` flag to sort by filename:

```
$ find . -depth -type d -exec find -s {} -maxdepth 1 -not -type d \; 
./A1/B1/f1
./A1/B1/f2
./A1/f1
./A1/f2
./A2/B1/C1/f1
./A2/B1/C1/f2
./A2/f1
./A2/f2
./f1
./f2
```

As @StéphaneChazelas points out in the comments, the `-s` flag is not available in OpenBSD.  Even where it is available, `find -s` also may break down depending on your locale, etc., as the man page says:

> Note: ‘find -s’ and ‘find | sort’ may give different results.

Comment: `find -s` seems to be available in FreeBSD and NetBSD, but not OpenBSD.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for noting that.  FWIW, OpenBSD's `ping` also doesn't implement a BSD enhancement, the `-o` switch. Odd.

Comment: in my Ubuntu 20.04 standard installed `find` command doesn't recognize `-s` switch|flag, as : 
"find: unknown predicate `-s'"